# Python list comprehension to group data

Tags: python, list-comprehension

The Data:

```
dictionary = {"user1" : "data1", "user2" : "data1", "user3": "data2"}
```

I want to summarize this dictionary to

```
dictionary2 = { "data1" : ["user1","user2"], "data2" : ["user3"] }
```

My Code:

```
dictionary2 = { b : [] for a,b in dictionary.items() }
[dictionary2[b].append(a) for a,b in dictionary.items()
```

I need to traverse dictionay twice to build dictionary2.

Is there any simpler way ?

Answer (score 7):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in original.iteritems():
   d[v].append(k)

print(d)
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer so the question is closed as answered.